# First mention of a particular result about $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I'm looking for the earliest mention of this little result:

> Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group acting on a finite set $S$. Let $X$ be the fixed point subset of $S$. Then the size of $X$ and the size of $S$ are congruent modulo $p$.

It might be Wielandt's Permutation Groups, however, I am not sure.

What is the oldest source containing this result?

Comment: What is your question? This follows by decomposing your set into orbits.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I edited the question to make it more clear. However I feel the original also stated that the question is for an  early or the original source of the result.

Comment: Perhaps this should go to history of math, then.

Comment: It's a consequence of (the formalism around) Burnside's lemma, which dates back to Burnside's 1897 book (though it was known before that). It's hard to talk about group theory much older than that, and it's a very easy result; are you should it wasn't just something widely known well before group theory was a separate field of study?